Another conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier issue
Anyway, this is for SQL Server 2022. The error only happens at run time, and only when I right click on the stored procedure in the list and select to execute.
When I click the execute button it runs without issue. When I click the parse button, it successfully finishes. So it is strictly a run-time error.
DECLARE IndexCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT PersonID AS NewUserID
    FROM Person as tblUser

OPEN IndexCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM IndexCursor INTO @UserID

INSERT INTO Workout (PersonID, ExerciseID, ExerciseTypeID)
    SELECT *
    FROM Exercise A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT @UserID, A.ExcerciseID, A.ExerciseTypeID
                      FROM Workout B
                      WHERE A.ExcerciseID = B.ExerciseID
    )

I have narrowed the issue down to the where clause. If I comment that out, I don't get the error, but it also runs on all data.
This is running a cursor to grab each userid, and grab it so it can be used to populate the workout table. The other data is already in the exercises table.
The idea is, if an exercise is added, it will add that exercise to each person's workout in the database. All of the fields and variables are set to be uniqueidentifier, so I really don't know why it has to convert anything to something it should already be set to.
I did find one difference in the two fields for the where clause, but I don't know how to fix it. B.ExerciseID has a default value of (newid()), A.exercise column does not.
I know I have misspellings of exercise, I need to go in and fix those. lol
I have tried CAST and CONVERT on @UserID in all instances that it appears. I have tried CAST on A.Exercise and B.Exercise, both in turn and at the same time. I looked and looked with googling different ideas. I have commented out parts of code to narrow down the actual line causing the issue (it wasn't until I did that, that I realized the @UserID variable was actually not causing the issue)
Update:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
    [PersonID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Weight] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [GoalWeight] [smallint] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PersonID] ASC)[PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Workout]
(
    [WrokoutID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PersonID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ExerciseID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ExerciseTypeID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Weight] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Reps] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Sets] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [NumberOfTimesCompleted] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DateOfLastCompletion] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Workout] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WrokoutID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Workout_WrokoutID]  
        DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [WrokoutID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Workout_ExerciseID]  
        DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [ExerciseID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Workout_Weight]  
        DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Weight]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Workout_Reps]  
        DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Reps]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Workout_Sets]  
        DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Sets]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Workout_NumberOfTimesCompleted]  
        DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [NumberOfTimesCompleted]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Workout_DateOfLastCompletion]  
        DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [DateOfLastCompletion]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ExcerciseNameToWorkout] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ExerciseID])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Exercise] ([ExcerciseID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ExcerciseNameToWorkout]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ExerciseTypeToWorkout] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ExerciseTypeID])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[ExerciseType] ([ExerciseTypeID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ExerciseTypeToWorkout]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_WorkoutToPerson] 
        FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([PersonID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Workout] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WorkoutToPerson]
GO


USE [WorkoutTracker]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Exercise]    Script Date: 10/27/2024 10:37:47 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Exercise](
    [ExcerciseID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ExerciseName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ExerciseTypeID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Exercise] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ExcerciseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Exercise] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Exercise_ExcerciseID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ExcerciseID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Exercise]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ExcerciseTypeToExcercise] FOREIGN KEY([ExerciseTypeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ExerciseType] ([ExerciseTypeID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Exercise] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ExcerciseTypeToExcercise]
GO


There's no "SSMS 2022" version - we have SQL Server 2022 (the actual database engine) - but the SSMS GUI tool is currently at v20.2. And you're also missing a closing ) in your WHERE NOT EXISTS clause ...

Please show us the structure of your tblUser and Workout tables....

The version of SSMS isn't even relevant, it's only a UI. It's the version of SQL Server (select @@version) that might be of use.

We need a [mre] in order to assist you. You've provided a rambling description without enough specific detail to assist you. And besides the error is clear, somewhere you are causing a value to be converted to a guid and it's failing.

You haven't provided any data for us to see where it's wrong ... Not any table definiteions... Hence the need for a mre... Which if you provided as requested, you would get an answer straight away

@marc_s I can output the structure of the tables, but it would be very hard to read. The column output on here just fall all over themselves, So I will post screen shots, but there could be a lot of them, because I will need one for each field. For starters I will just start with the ID fields in question.  For clarification, The server is running SQL Server 2022. The SSMS is 20.4. Sorry I got them mixed up. Also the closing ) was there, I just missed it on copy.

Do not use images, script the tables to produce a create table statement.

If as you say it's in your where clause then it must be ExerciseId because that's the only column used. Btw you do realise that using column in a select sub-query in an exists does nothing, you can replace them with 1 for the logic required.

You don't appear to have provided the definition of the Exercise table - which is the other side of the where clause.

@DaleK Sorry I was only asked for the user and workout table. I will get the other one right now.

Select * from Exercise is never going to work because it has different columns to Workout

You could simplify your SQL code a lot by tossing the CURSOR, and also combining the SQL to select the two fixed variables.
I've come up with this, but obviously can't really test it, since I don't have your database at my disposal:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateUserWorkouts]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- the IF EXISTS only checks for existence - it doesn't return any data
    -- no need to specify multiple columns here - SELECT * will do fine    
    IF EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM dbo.Exercise 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Workout ON  dbo.Exercise.ExcerciseID = dbo.Workout.ExerciseID
               WHERE (dbo.Workout.WrokoutID IS NULL))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ExerciseID uniqueidentifier
        DECLARE @ExerciseTypeID uniqueidentifier

        -- use a single SELECT, and set the two variable, in a single statement
        SELECT 
            @ExerciseID = Exercise.ExcerciseID,
            @ExerciseTypeID = Exercise.ExerciseTypeID 
        FROM 
            dbo.Exercise 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            dbo.Workout ON dbo.Exercise.ExcerciseID = dbo.Workout.ExerciseID 
        WHERE 
            dbo.Workout.WrokoutID IS NULL

        -- do the INSERT INTO as a single, set-based SQL statement
        INSERT INTO dbo.Workout (PersonID, ExerciseID, ExerciseTypeID)
            SELECT 
                PersonID, @ExerciseID, @ExerciseTypeID
            FROM
                dbo.Person
    END


Oh I like this @marc_s.  I will try it out tonight.  Thanks. SQL is obviously not my strong suit.  Alas, here I am though, doing a favor for a buddy. Like the sucker I am. Lol

the code works exactly as expected. Thank you for the optimization.

After playing with this I chose to go a completely different direction. I went with an if statement to check for the missing records, then if there were any I stepped through gathering the infromation long hand. Then inserted it all in the table at the end. Here is the finished product. I know it is ugly and would love suggestions on how to reduce clutter, for example that same select clause I use over three times.
USE [WorkoutTracker]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateUserWorkouts]    Script Date: 10/27/2024 10:28:37 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateUserWorkouts]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT    Exercise.ExcerciseID, Exercise.ExerciseTypeID     
        FROM            dbo.Exercise LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                 dbo.Workout ON  dbo.Exercise.ExcerciseID = dbo.Workout.ExerciseID
        WHERE        (dbo.Workout.WrokoutID IS NULL)
        )
    BEGIN

    

    DECLARE @UserID uniqueidentifier
    DECLARE @ExerciseID uniqueidentifier
    DECLARE @ExerciseTypeID uniqueidentifier

    SET @ExerciseID = (SELECT Exercise.ExcerciseID FROM dbo.Exercise LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Workout ON  dbo.Exercise.ExcerciseID = dbo.Workout.ExerciseID WHERE (dbo.Workout.WrokoutID IS NULL))
    SET @ExerciseTypeID = (SELECT Exercise.ExerciseTypeID FROM dbo.Exercise LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Workout ON  dbo.Exercise.ExcerciseID = dbo.Workout.ExerciseID WHERE (dbo.Workout.WrokoutID IS NULL))

    DECLARE IndexCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT PersonID AS NewUserID
        FROM Person as tblUser

    OPEN IndexCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM IndexCursor INTO @UserID


        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Workout
                (
                    PersonID
                    , ExerciseID
                    , ExerciseTypeID
                )
            VALUES 
                (
                    @UserID
                    , @ExerciseID
                    , @ExerciseTypeID
                )

            FETCH NEXT FROM IndexCursor INTO @UserID

        END

    Close IndexCursor
    DEALLOCATE IndexCursor

    END

